# PostgreSQL INSERT ON CONFLICT and TKinter

Tags: python, postgresql

I have problem with syntax within python/Tkinter when updating PostgreSQL table.

Syntax works for function code below without ON CONFLICT option:

```
def myclick_start():
# Create a database or connect to one
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="*",# hidden credentials here 
                    host="*",
                    user="*",
                    password="*",
                    port="*")

# Create cursor
c = conn.cursor()

# Insert Into Database Table
thing1 = o_num.get()
thing2 = op_id.get()
thing3 = proc_name_cb.get()

# this works
c.execute('''INSERT INTO orders (order_id, op_id, status_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''',
          (thing1, thing2, thing3)
          )

# Commit Changes
conn.commit()

# Close Connection
conn.close()
```

but not working when I want to UPDATE table ON CONFLICT of `order_id` value:

```
# but this is not working    
c.execute('''INSERT INTO orders (order_id, op_id, status_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''',
              (thing1, thing2, thing3),
              ON CONFLICT (order_id)
                 DO UPDATE SET op_id = EXCLUDED.op_id, status_id = EXCLUDED.status_id;
              )
```

Resulted error:

```
File "E:\***.py", line 229
'''c.execute('''INSERT INTO orders (order_id, op_id, status_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''',
                ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried many syntax variants and kind of stuck with my error.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the syntax highlight, you will notice that your `ON CONFLICT ...` isn't part of the SQL query (i.e. it's not part of the string that makes up the query).

Moving that part inside the string should solve the problem, like this

```py
c.execute('''INSERT INTO orders (order_id, op_id, status_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
             ON CONFLICT (order_id)
             DO UPDATE SET op_id = EXCLUDED.op_id, status_id = EXCLUDED.status_id;''',
             (thing1, thing2, thing3)
          )
```

Comment: Lifesaver... Worked like a charm - thanks a million....

Comment: @ericpolter no worries, glad I could help!